# Why is $lg(\theta(\frac{1}{n}))$ = $\theta(\frac{1}{n})$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I'm trying to follow a proof of an exercise from an algorithms textbook, and am confused about one the algebraic steps in the proof:

$lg(\theta(\frac{1}{n}))$ = $\theta(\frac{1}{n})$

Where $lg$ is $log_2$ (although base doesn't matter asymptotically). The full proof is at http://clrs.skanev.com/03/02/03.html

Wouldn't the asymptotic behavior of any $lg(f(x))$ function be different from just $f(x)$?

I should note that the proof is from a study group of the textbook and not from the textbook itself, so might be more likely to have mistakes.

Comment: I think it may be due to the approximation $\log (1+x) \approx x$.

Comment: Hmm - that doesn't make much sense to me, e.g. $ln(1 + 80) = 4.39$, nowhere near 80. And the plot of $ln(x)$ is not linear. Do you where that approximation comes from?

Comment: At the link there are factorials involved, did you drop one or more?

Comment: @QuadrupleA $\log(1 + x) \simeq x$ for small values of $x$, as can be seen by taking the Taylor expansion of $\log(1 + x)$ about $x = 0$.

Comment: @coffeemath Well the proof is to show that $lg(n!) = \theta(n lg n)$, and uses Stirling's approximation of $n!$ as a starting point (it's the parameter to the $lg()$ function to the right of the first equals sign of the proof). So there are no factorials on the 'Stirling' side in this case.

Comment: @qaphla Ah - so in this case the proof is looking at asymptotic bounds of the function, where $n$ could be arbitrarily large, so I assume approximations for small $n$ wouldn't really be applicable.

Comment: @QuadrupleA For large $n$, $\frac{1}{n}$ is small...

Comment: @qaphla Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof you linked to isn't very good. The whole issue could be avoided by noting that $\sqrt{2\pi n}(1 + \Theta(\frac1n)) = \Theta(\sqrt n)$ at the beginning.

The author's approach is still ok in principle, but they make a mistake when they replace $\log(\Theta(1)+\Theta(\frac1n))$ with $\Theta(\frac1n)$. The expression $\log(\Theta(1)+\Theta(\frac1n))$ is simply the logarithm of a bounded function, which could either be undefined or (if the function is bounded away from $0$) itself bounded, but not $\Theta(\frac1n)$ in general. It is true that the original $\log(1+\Theta(\frac1n))$ is legitimately $\Theta(\frac1n)$; this follows from the Taylor approximation to $\log(1+x)$ at $x=0$, as per qaphia's comment, and is probably what the author meant.

Note also that the author's "proof" that $n! = o(n^n)$ is incorrect: it shows that $n! \le n^n$, but that's not as strong as $o(n^n)$. (It's easy to modify the proof to get the additional information - just don't change the initial $1$ to an $n$, and get the upper bound $n^{n-1}$.)